# Can you use System.Net.Sockets tcp client in Unity3D for Hololens 2 UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, tcp, uwp

Is it possible to use the standard `System.Net.Sockets` library to implement a tcp client/server in Unity3D for the Hololens 2, meaning UWP?

Or do you need to use `Windows.Networking.Sockets` specifically? I have read conflicting information online. Maybe some one can clear things up for me once and for all.

I can get it to work with `System.Net.Sockets` inside the Unity Editor. However, when building to the Hololens 2, a connection cannot be established. The necessary capabilites have been set under publishing settings.

Comment: Do you have your log file? And yeah according to e.g. [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/foxypanda.me/tcp-client-in-a-uwp-unity-app-on-hololens/amp/) I think you would use `Windows.Networking.Sockets` on a UWP build and `System.Net.Sockets` in the editor ...

Comment: @derHugo I read this article too. But its from 2017. And who would have thought, I just built another version without immediate run and it works now! Which is great news! This means the ```System.Net.Sockets``` lib is supported on the Hololens. I did not read this anywhere tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is already resolved, but I have done a TCP Client and Server in Unity on multiple platforms and should work on everything but WebGL. This is why I moved to using SignalR in my Unity projects for real time communications. SignalR will need a separate, centralized server, whereas TCP can be used for peer to peer communicating, so it still has some good use over SignalR.

Kevin Kaymak on YouTube has excellent videos on making a TCP Server/Client in Unity. This is his 2020 playlist on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOBSAFmL610&list=PLI9CK8e_e3MeDv8K1vi0FosBV4dKmcOo3

It is way too much code to post obviously but I don't think setting it up was your issue. If you want the code, I made a Github repo years ago that should still work today that implements Kevin Kaymak's code from 2018: https://github.com/Vdrio/BaseTCPServer